How to obtain the probability density function of the random variable associated with two processes?
Imagine there’s a faucet that’s controlled by two random sequences, $a_i$ and $b_i$, which determine how long it stays open and closed, respectively. Let’s say the PDFs of $a_i$s and $b_i$s are $f_A(a)$ and $f_B(b)$, respectively. Additionally, $a_i$ is independent of $b_i$. The faucet keeps switching between being on and off. The $i$-th off time is $a_i$ and the $i$-th on time is $b_i$. Now, there’s a conveyor belt with a line of cups moving underneath it. Each cup pauses under the faucet for exactly 1 second before moving on. If we define a random variable $c$ as the amount of time each cup actually gets water, how would we find the PDF of $c$?
I think since the faucet keeps switching on and off, the start times for each “on” period are constantly changing. I need to sum up all the previous open and closed times to determine when the current open phase begins and ends. This requires convolving multiple $f_A(a)$ and $f_B(b)$ distributions, which gets pretty complicated and makes it hard to find a closed-form expression. Plus, I also need to match this with the timing of the conveyor belt to figure out when the cup actually gets water. There’s also the chance that a cup could go through several open/close cycles while it’s under the faucet. I’m really hoping to get some different perspectives or ideas from you all on how to approach finding the PDF of $c$. I also drew a diagram to help with the analysis, as shown below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!


It seems you don't really have two random variables $a$ and $b$, you have two sequences $a_i$ and $b_i$. Are these all assumed to be independent?  You need to say so.  Also there's not just one $c$, there's a sequence of them.  And there's no reason to think that those all have the same distribution, nor are they independent.

The distribution of the amount of time a cup gets water will depend on the open/closed state of the faucet when this cup's interval starts, and how long that state has been going on (unless $a_i$ and $b_i$ have exponential distributions).

@RobertIsrael Yes, you are correct, there are actually two random sequences, namely, $a_i$ and $b_i$, where the sequence $a_i$ follows the distribution $f_A(a)$ and the sequence $b_i$ follows distribution $f_B(b)$. Each element within the $a_i$ is independent of the others, and similarly, each element within the $b_i$ is also independent. Additionally, $a_i$ is independent of $b_i$. The PDF of $f_A(a)$ and $f_B(b)$ are not necessarily the same.

@RobertIsraelThe state of the faucet—whether it's open or closed—at the start of this cup's interval also hinges on its previous states, as it requires knowing how much time has elapsed. Additionally, after running the simulation, I noticed that the time before the facet starts working, i.e., the time between the start of a cup's interval and $a_1$, would affect the PDF of $c$, i.e., $f_C(c)$.
